# How to use theme() function in config (tailwind)

Tags: css, sass, tailwind-css, tailwind-in-js, tailwind-ui

I am trying to create 1 reusable gap variable that I can use everywhere I have multiple buttons next to each other. Instead of using `gap-3` I want just to use `gap-buttons`

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      gap: {
        buttons: theme(theme.gap.3),
      },
    },
  },
};
```

The error I am getting is `Maximum call stack size exceeded`. I tried `buttons: (theme) => theme(theme.gap.3)` also did not work. Also with colors, it is not working...

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
       alert: theme => theme('colors.red')
      }
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: Hi, did my answer helped somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I do have this kind of code in one of my projects, not sure if it may help (that one is tailwind v1, with no `extend`)

```js
borderColor: (theme) => ({
  ...theme('colors'),
  default: theme('colors.gray.300', 'currentColor'),
}),
```

It would look like this with your code

```js
colors: (theme) => ({
  alert: theme('colors.red')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You're are referencig the function inside it self, creating an infinite loop and thus exceding js callstack. The `theme` function is calling the `colors` function inside the `colors` functions. Got it? It's a circular reference. Try to log `theme` and you'll see.

What you want is a reference to the default values. You just have to import them like this:

```
import { fontFamily, fontSize } from "tailwindcss/defaultTheme";
```

Or using `require`, if you're using cjs.

The downside is that it won't update accordingly if you override any of the default values. If you need something like this, look into plugins, they might fit your needs. Something like this:

```
    addUtilities({
        ".gap-buttons": {
            "gap": theme('gap.3'),
        },
    });
```